# not authorized to perform operation polkit authority not available

Tags: 18.04, hard-drive, remote-desktop, xrdp, policykit

I have successfully set up remote connection to a PC (which uses linux) via XRDP. the system from which the connection is lunched is on Windows 10. when using remote connection, I am not given permission to access external drives such as flash disks and also other partitions of the host (linux-based) system. However, I can access those drives via the host system (without remote connection) itself directly. how should I solve this problem? any suggestions?

[image: not authorized to perform operation polkit authority not available]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remote connections such as Remote Desktop / xrdp sessions have permissions separately from local sessions.

Authorizations are handled by polkit.

Try the following:

To see details for registered actions, you can run:
`pkaction --verbose | more`

What you need to do is identify the registered action (policy file) for what you are trying to do. If the registered action works locally but not remotely, you can change

`ResultInactive=no` to `ResultInactive=yes` in that policy file.

After that, reboot or restart the associated service.